# internet explorer is showing a pink strip

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on the site http://childrensdentalland.com/ and it is a wordpress site. When viewed from all the browser except IE ,the site is showing ok but when We views through IE it shows a pink strip under the 
"Welcome To Phoenix Pediatric Dental Specialists".

Can anyone help me to correct this problem.
Thanks
Somdeb

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Every version from 7 to 9 seems to show the issue.  Looks like the `.navshadow` div is out of place.  I'm gonna blame the 61px margin.

Comment: Can I see your CSS code. And HTML

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck rightclick inspect element? Or f12?

Answer (score 0):

hmm could have something to do with float. your navDiv has no float which can break things in browsers.

Check your margins and heights as well. make them set and that may as well fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your class. I did this in Firefox just to see what happened. But anyways. I think it is because it needs to have `float:left;` . I don't have IE with dev tools so I am sort of taking a shot in the dark.

```
.footshadow {
float:left;
margin-top:13px; /*this will have to be tweaked*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird absolute positioning going on there.

What you should be doing instead is floating .menu-header left, #searchpedi right, and then clearing both on .navshadow. Remove all position: absolute and use float instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it very simple you just define one properties in you css file `.navshadow{top:221px;}`

as like this

```
.navshadow {top:221px;}
```